# Discover clipped elements

Tags: javascript, svg

If I clip a bunch of SVG elements, is there some way to use the SVG API to determine whether each of those elements is affected by the clip?

In other words, given the following:

```
<svg>
 <defs>
    <clipPath id="aClip">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="90" height="90"/>
    </clipPath>
 </defs>
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"  clip-path="url(#aClip)" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="10"  clip-path="url(#aClip)" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="10"  clip-path="url(#aClip)" />
</svg>
```

..is there any way I can tell which circle elements are clipped without resorting to drawing the elements and using canvas to check for raster overlap?